# How to determine the domain (intersection and disjoint set) of two functions define on a set?

Tags: functions, intersection, sets, subset

Suppose I have two multivariate functions $f(x,y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)$ such that $0<x<1,0<y<1,0<z<1$.  $f(x,y,z)$ is defined on values satisfying $\{0<x<1,0<y<1/2, z>y\}$ or $\{0<x<1/2,1/2<y<1,0<z<1\}$.

However, $g(x,y,z)$ is defined on $\{ x+y<z, z>y \}$ or $\{ 0<x<1/2,0<y<2x,0<z<1/2 \}$.

I want to determine intervals in which either one of these functions is defined (either $f(x,y,z)$ or $g(x,y,z)$ are defined) or both of them are defined.

Comment: Is this pertaining to the software Mathematica? If so, check `ImplicitRegion`, `RegionIntersection`, etc.